# Nissan Xtrail 2006 NT30 Reverse not working (Slipping)

Tags: automatic-transmission, nissan, x-trail

My Nissan XTrail NT30 (2006) 4WD Auto Transmission, all forward gears are working fine, but reverse is slipping. However, I can reverse fine on flat surface, but cannot reverse at all up hill.

What seems to be the problem? Is it something that can be fixed or do I have to replace the gear box?

Comment: Transmission needs an overhaul or replacement.

Comment: but the front gears are working, only the reverse is not.